# How do I deny an app Accessibility Access forever?

Tags: mojave, security, permission

I recently installed an app on my system (Mac OS X Mojave) and it showed an permissions dialog:

*"[appname]" would like to control this computer using accessibility features. …*

I got two buttons:

1. Open System Preferences
2. Deny

I know the app wants me to go to system prefs and allow it access. I know how to do that. But I don't want to grant it the permissions it asks for. Therefore I click *Deny*.

The dialog closes, but on the next system start it askes again. Every time.

Is my only choice as a user to grant it the permission it wants to get rid of it or deny it every time the system starts?

**How do I deny the permission forever?**

(I know I should grant it or uninstall, but then why am I offered an option to deny if I should not do that?)

**Example**: the app always ask me like this, very annoying.

[image]

Comment: Hi, it might help if you post what app you're trying to do this with. This allows someone else to reproduce the issue and maybe identify something unique about the app or your setup. Looking forward to testing with the app in question!

Comment: It's the "lghub_agent.app" (Logitech G Hub Software) for example. But I have seen this with some other Apps too.

Comment: I'm also interested in the answer to this question too